# xbindkeys && xdotool => spontaneous disabling mouse buttons

Tags: mouse, xbindkeys, xdotool

I have Logitech G500s mouse, and configure extra buttons via xbindkeys && xdotool.

```
# Scroll Left = "previous Tab" in Browser
"xdotool key Ctrl+Tab"
b:7

# Scroll right = "next Tab" in Browser
"xdotool key Ctrl+Shift+Tab"
b:6

"xdotool key Alt+Left"
b:8

"xdotool key Alt+Right"
b:9

#Present Windows
"xdotool key F5"
b:10
```

But some times buttons 6 & 7 stop working, until I run `xinput test <mouse id>`
Wich tools can I use, to diagnose problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Possible problem is xdotool.
I switch to xmacro and all buttons work fine.